# How to enable/disable any rule from SonarLint in Eclipse

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I have SonarLint installed in Eclipse and there is a remotely set up sonarQube server, but rules are different on both . How can I configure rules same as SonarQube on SonarLint in my Eclipse ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the connected mode in order to apply the same ruleset on your IDE that the one running on your SonarQube instance. 
Have a look at the relevant documentation : 
http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/#Connected

Comment: Can I have diff rule set for my local machine means can I disable some rules which are enable on remote server

Comment: Yes you can do an initial sync and then unchecked the rules in the Rules tab under SonarLint general settings

Answer (score 18):

I thought I would leave this up here for anyone looking.....

To Disable/Re-Enable Rules in SonarLint/Eclipse.
-Window-Preferences-SonarLint-Rules Configuration.
-Select Your Language(in my case Java).
-Select the drop for changed rules or open the + symbol to show all rules.

Answer (score 4):

In your Java code, you can disable a specific rule for a single method using annotations:

```java
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("java:S2699")
```